# How to calculate the jerk from acceleration data?

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, jerk

I have speed data from the GPS transmitter of a Truck which reports the speed of the vehicle at a fixed time interval. I can calculate the acceleration/deceleration of the truck by doing a $\frac{v_2-v_1}{t_2-t_1}$ calculation. However, can I calculate the jerk in the same manner? That is $\frac{a_2-a_1}{t_2-t_1}$? Will that be a correct thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. The jerk is the 3'rd derivative of position with respect to time, which is the change in acceleration per unit time. Keep in mind that position, velocity, acceleration, and jerk are vectors. Your formula would compute the magnitude of the jerk. To compute its vector, you would use your formula and treat the acceleration as vectors.

Comment: Do you know, how to calculte it with Matlab? I have to find it out. I just started learning MATLAB